# My Guess The Number Game Will Not Loop Back to Beginning

Tags: python

```
import random
control = True
main = True
count = 0

user = input("Would you like to play Guess The Number?")
if (user == "yes"):
    while (control == True):
        randgen = random.randrange(0, 100)
        print("Guess a random number")
        while main == True:
            number = int(input())
            if (number == randgen):
                print("Great Job you guessed the correct number")
                print("You have tried ", count, "time(s)")
                main = False
                control = False

            if (number < randgen):
                count += 1
                print("Your number is smaller than the random number")
                print("You are at ", count, "trie(s)")
                main = True
            if (number > randgen):
                count += 1
                print("Your number is larger than the random number")
                print("You are at ", count, "trie(s)")
                main = True
        again = int(input("Would you like to play again?1 for yes and 2 for no."))
        if (again == 1):
            control = True

            user = ("yes")
        if (again == 2):
            control = False
            print ("Ok bye bye")
            ##user ("no")

if (user == "no"):
    print ("OK then Bye")
```

This Code works except for the part that when I want to play again it does not work. I have a coding background in java that's why I know some code but I made the guess the number game in java and I cannot figure out whats wrong with my python version(posted above).

Comment: How does it not work? What do you input, what do you see, and what do you expect? It looks as if it should work from a visual inspection, so please explain further. BTW, the brackets around `if (expression):` are not necessary, and `while control:` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Please simplify your question: make your example minimal. What have you tried to make it work? Have you tested the value of your variable `again`?

Comment: The issue is "main" is being set to False when we enter the game the second time, hence it never enters the while loop that generates the number and checks. So if the user enters 1, set main to True.

Comment: Often it is simpler to go into an infinite loop `while True:` and just `break` out of the loop when you want it to end. Trying to maintain some variable to check when you should rerun the loop or break out just muddies the waters with unnecessary variable names.

Comment: As others have commented, please provide more information about the problem. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make these changes:

```
if (again == 1):
    control = True
    main=True
    user = ("yes")
```